# Access 2010 Form Additions without Edits and Deletions

Tags: ms-access-2010

On Microsoft Access 2010, I have a database set up. In this database, I have id numbers for the animals I am working with, and the tests I run on each one. I am attempting to make it so that my researchers can add to the database using a form when new tests are run, but not be allowed to make any edits or deletions to the test results already inputted.

I have tried setting the properties of the form as follows:

Additions: Yes

Edits: No

Deletions: No

This does not allow me to add any new data to the form though. When I set edits to yes, I can then add new data and edit the existing data, which is not what I want. Is there any way to fix this? Preferably without code, or explaining the method of vba in detail if that is the only way to fix the problem.

Comment: Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx acFormDataMode - you can give different people different privileges.

Comment: I have tried this page, thank you. It allows different people to have different privileges, but each one allows both additions and edits, while I want only additions.

Comment: I think you have failed to examine acFormDataMode, please read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191834.aspx

Comment: I did see that, and I would assume I need the "0" data add mode. But I have researched for a few days and still do not understand how to get into data mode, how to use vba, etc. This is our labs first time using access

Comment: I am not getting this, you are the designer, why have you a problem? Have you not got a front and back-end? If so, you are looking for problems.

Comment: I designed the database, yes. I do not understand how to get to the datamode described in the side you posted, it seems like some knowledge on code is needed. We have split the database into front and back end, but the researchers can still edit that data in my database, which I do not want. They need to ONLY be able to add new data using a form.

Comment: If you have a front and back-end, you get the copy with a form that allows everything, everyone else gets the add-only copy. The point of my original suggestion was that you had a menu, but it does not seem relevant here.

Comment: When I messed with the back-end vs. front end copies, I was able to change data as well as add. Is this because it was still on my computer? If so, how to I get it to a different computer?

Comment: You need two front-end copies, one for the other guys with no edits, one for you, with edits.

Comment: So the one I give to the researchers would automatically be additions only? Or I need to change settings to make it that way?

Comment: You set up the researchers to be add-only and yourself to be a demi-god.

Comment: Okay, this brings me to my original question. How to I make it add only? When I set it to additions only on yes, as the properties above, it does not allow for any changes, including additions

Comment: Does the recordset on which the form is based allow additions?

Comment: The form is based on the database, which I have looked in the properties and have found nowhere to allow or disallow additions on the database.

Comment: Open the table or query on which the form is based in the front-end, does it allow additions?

Comment: Yes, I can edit, delete, and add on the table which the form is based on.

Comment: Okay, you win. I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help though! I though I was just stupid/ crazy for awhile there.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any standard Access feature to have recordset-fields locked and unlocked only for new recordsets in one form.

You could use a workaround (with VBA):

Form properties:

Additions: Yes

Edits: Yes

Deletions: No

In the field properties:

set each field Locked: Yes

In the enter- and leave-event for each field add this (Replace FIELDNAME with the actual fieldname)

```
Private Sub FIELDNAME_Enter()
    If Me.NewRecord Then
       Me.FieldName.Locked = False
    Else
       'to be sure...
       Me.FieldName.Locked = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FIELDNAME_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.FieldName.Locked = True
End Sub
```

**But** I would strongly suggest to create a second form only for input Data.
You should set the second form properties to *Data Entry* = true (I am not sure if  *Data Entry* is right due to translation) or do it by VBA Command openForm  with parameter DataMode:=acFormAdd

You could then open the second "input"-form from the first form via button.